# map tracking active in UIViewController should continue when pop back in ios

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, mkmapview

I'm doing an app to calculate distance of user travelled

in which it has hierarchy like Login(UIViewController)==>Tabbar contoller(in which it is having 4 UIViewController with nav controllers)

its like

```
              nav Controller==>viewcontroller1==>map
              nav Controller==>viewcontroller1==>someotherviewcontroller
```

tabbarContoller==>

```
              nav Controller==>viewcontroller1==>someotherviewcontroller
              nav Controller==>viewcontroller1==>someotherviewcontroller
```

if i go to tabbar and from Tab1 I'll go to add trip view (which is map view)

then in Map view i'll start trip means I'll calculate distance if I start and go back to tabbar and go to other tabs

mapview should continue tracking and when i again go to that view
it has to show all the distance

but in my case it is again showing map and not continuing

how to do this

Answer (score 0):

As you go back the NavigationController dealloc your controller object so you cant make it to keep tracking, I would suggest create a **Singleton** class for calculation and can notify your viewController as required.

Comment: i'm new to ios can u give any link or tutorial to do this

Comment: Here are all basic software design pattern for iOS development which you must know http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Comment: Any body helps to this is so appreciated